# Dynamic row in a cell sequence

Tags: excel, dynamic, range, cell

I need some help with a formula reference.

For example, I have a formula A1=sheet!$B20.
Then on the next row I need it to be A2=sheet!$B47, then A3=sheet!$B74... etc.

The reference cells - 20, 47, 74 etc. - I have in another column from which I want to read the numbers and when I drag the formula from A1 downwards I would like the formula to take these values automatically.

How can I do that ?

Comment: How do you know A1 should map to B20?  As it reads now, it seems arbitrary, and Excel doesn't do arbitrary.

Comment: @pnuts Ah, I see that now, thanks ... with apologies to the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=INDIRECT("sheet!$B" & C1)
```

Assuming values are in C1 and down

Comment: Well, that for sure... but, in this case, is almost irrelevant :)

Comment: Ok, to be 100% consistent with OP I will edit sheet name... :)